# Is it possible to install npm without python 2?

Tags: python-3.x, npm, google-apps-script, ubuntu-20.04, clasp

Context: I would like to install clasp via npm for Google Apps Script development. I'm on Ubuntu 20.04.

`apt-get -s install npm` shows my machine trying to install python 2 - which I don't have and don't want.

Is it possible to install npm (and therefore clasp) without having to accept python 2 and getting mired in python version problems on my machine?

Answer (score 2):

No, I'm quite sure npm needs python 2. I have both python 2 & 3 on my ubuntu 20.04, and I've never had any problems caused by using both.

Also, you should probably use apt install instead of apt-get (not a significant change just, more modern and faster). Here is a link on the differences: https://itsfoss.com/apt-vs-apt-get-difference/